# how i can achieve this UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

[image]

Here I'm having a list of week with DayName and Date when I click on a specific Date a widget will popup where I have my task.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to get position of clicked date card :
[from link](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-finding-x-and-y-coordinates-of-a-widget-at-runtime/)

```
void _getOffset(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox? box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    Offset? position = box?.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (position != null) {
      setState(() {
        _x = position.dx;
        _y = position.dy;
      });
    }
  }
```

now you can use `alert dialog` widget wraped with `alignment`, and pass x and y from previous function.

Comment: no it's not working because alignment x & y only take range from -1.0 to 1.0